# Scrapy extract table data if table exists

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping this website https://www.handbook.fca.org.uk/handbook/PRIN/3/?date=2030-12-01&timeline=True&view=chapter and I'd like to parse the table data as well if the table exists in the page. I have tried catching table element on conditional basis but it is not working with that approach. Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urlencode


class HandBook(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "handbook_spider"

    custom_settings = {
        "LOG_FILE": "handbook_spider.log",
        "ITEM_PIPELINES": {
            "handbook_spider.pipelines.HandbookExcelPipeline": 300,
        },
    }

    headers = {
        "authority": "www.handbook.fca.org.uk",
        "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        "accept-language": "en,ru;q=0.9",
        "cache-control": "max-age=0",
        "sec-ch-ua": '"Chromium";v="106", "Yandex";v="22", "Not;A=Brand";v="99"',
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
        "sec-ch-ua-platform": '"Linux"',
        "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
        "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
        "sec-fetch-site": "cross-site",
        "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
        "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 YaBrowser/22.11.3.832 (beta) Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36",
    }

    params = {
        "date": "2030-12-01",
        "timeline": "True",
        "view": "chapter",
    }

    url = "https://www.handbook.fca.org.uk/handbook/PRIN/3/?"

    def start_requests(self):
        base_url = self.url + urlencode(self.params)
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=base_url, headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse_details
        )

    def parse_details(self, response):
        for content in response.css("div.handbook-content"):
            chapter_ref = content.xpath(
                "./header/h1/span[@class='extended']/text()"
            ).get()
            chapter = "".join(content.xpath("./header/h1/text()").getall()).strip()
            topic = None
            for section in content.css("section"):
                header = section.css("header")
                table_content = section.css("div.section-content-table")
                if header:
                    topic = header.css("h2.crosstitle::text").get()
                if table_content:
                    topic = section.css("h3::text").get()
                    content = section.css("td ::text").getall()
                    clause_text = " ".join(list(content))
                else:
                    content = section.xpath(
                        ".//div[@class='section-content']//text()"
                    ).getall()
                    clause_text = " ".join(list(map(str.strip, content)))
                    uid = section.xpath(".//span[@class='extended']/text()").get()
                    if section.css("span.section-type").get() is not None:
                        yield {
                            "Unique_ids": uid,
                            "Chapter_ref": chapter_ref,
                            "Chapter": chapter,
                            "Topic": topic,
                            "Clause": uid.split(".")[-2],
                            "Sub_Clause": uid.split(".")[-1],
                            "Type": section.css("span.section-type::text").get(),
                            "Date_applicable": section.xpath(
                                ".//time/span/text()"
                            ).get(),
                            "Text": clause_text,
                        }
```

scraper totally missing `PRIN 3.3.1` section. Please anyone can help me out figure out parsing that table?

Comment: you just want to extract all the text in the table into one field?

Comment: yes all the table text into text column.

Comment: is there any better idea to format that table text into excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is skipping section with the table is because you are parsing the table in the `if table_content:` block. Since the parse method only ever yields an item from the `else` block, when `if table_content` is `True` it never executes the `else` block and no item is ever yielded.

Here is an example of how you could make it work.

```
    def parse_details(self, response):
        for content in response.css("div.handbook-content"):
            chapter_ref = content.xpath(
                "./header/h1/span[@class='extended']/text()"
            ).get()
            chapter = "".join(content.xpath("./header/h1/text()").getall()).strip()
            topic = None
            for section in content.css("section"):
                header = section.css("h2.crosstitle::text")
                if header:
                    topic = header.get()
                else:
                    table_content = section.css("div.section-content-table")
                    if table_content:
                        topic = section.xpath(".//header/h3/text()").get()
                        content = table_content.xpath(".//table//text()").getall()
                    else:
                        content = section.xpath(
                            ".//div[@class='section-content']//text()"
                        ).getall()
                    clause_text = " ".join(list(map(str.strip, content)))
                    uid = section.xpath(".//span[@class='extended']/text()").get()
                    if section.css("span.section-type").get() is not None:
                        yield {
                            "Unique_ids": uid,
                            "Chapter_ref": chapter_ref,
                            "Chapter": chapter,
                            "Topic": topic,
                            "Clause": uid.split(".")[-2],
                            "Sub_Clause": uid.split(".")[-1],
                            "Type": section.css("span.section-type::text").get(),
                            "Date_applicable": section.xpath(
                                ".//time/span/text()"
                            ).get(),
                            "Text": clause_text,
                        }
```

Comment: Awesome! once again thank you so much!